# Sequelize v3 — how do I make the default value for a hasMany relationship an empty list?

Tags: javascript, associations, sequelize.js, model-associations

I am using [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com) as my ORM. I have a simple `User` model as follows. A `User` `hasMany` `comments`, and a `Comment` `belongsTo` a `user`.

`models/user.js` (trimmed to what's relevant)

```
const model = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const User = sequelize.define('User', {
      name: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
      }
    },
    {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          User.hasMany(models.Comment, {as: 'comments'})
        }
      }
    }
  )

  return User
}

module.exports = model
```

`models/comment.js` (also trimmed)

```
const model = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {

  const Comment = sequelize.define('Comment', {
      text: {
        type: DataTypes.TEXT
      }
    }, {
      classMethods: {
        associate: function(models) {
          Comment.belongsTo(models.User, {as: 'author'})
        }
      }
    }
  )

  return Comment
}

module.exports = model
```

I've created a test as follows (trimmed for brevity)

```
describe('create user given simple valid data', () => {
  const userData = {
    name: 'test'
  }

  it('creates a user', (done) => {
    User.create(userData, {
      include: [{model: models.Comment, as: 'comments'}]
    }).then((user) => {
      const userJS = user.get({plain: true})
      expect(userJS).to.have.property('name')
      expect(userJS).to.have.property('comments')
      done()
    }, done)
  })
})
```

which results in

```
Unhandled rejection AssertionError: expected { Object (name, ...) } to have a property 'comments'
```

If I specify my `userData` like this however

```
const userData = {
  name: 'test',
  comments: []
}
```

the test passes just fine.

How can I tell Sequelize to just make an empty list of comments as the default?

Comment: I think you have to get comments manually by: `user.getComments()`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this feature is not part of the models creation.

It relates to the Query when getting data.
You can use the nested:true option in include statement of findAll.

```
User.findAll({ 
    include: [{ 
    model: Comment, 
    as: "comments", 
    nested: true 
}]});
```

source: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/models-usage.html#nested-eager-loading